# SQL Subquery returned more than 1 Value from if else statement

Tags: sql, t-sql

This is a statement from one of my stored procedures

```
IF @Action = 'UPDATE'
BEGIN
IF (Select Nome 
    From hDados hd 
    JOIN hRequisicao hr 
        ON hr.IdReq = hd.IdReq 
    WHERE hr.IdColaborador = 3 
    AND IdStatus != 4 
    AND IdStatus != 5) LIKE @Nome
    UPDATE hDados
    SET Nome = @Nome, 
        Dados = @Dados, 
        Observacoes = @Observacoes
    FROM hRequisicao hr, hDados hd
    WHERE hr.IdColaborador = @IdColaborador 
    AND Nome LIKE @Nome 
    AND IdStatus != 4 
    AND IdStatus != 5
ELSE
    INSERT INTO hDados(Nome,Dados,Observacoes,IdReq) 
    VALUES (
        @Nome,
        @Dados,
        @Observacoes,
        (
         Select hr.IdReq 
         From hRequisicao hr 
         WHERE hr.IdColaborador = @IdColaborador 
         AND IdStatus != 4 
         AND IdStatus != 5
        )
   )
END
```

Problem is, I need to check if the parameter returned from Application exists in the table `hDados` using the select command only where the `IdColaborador = @IdColaborador` but this doesn't work cause it says it returns more than 1 value. How am i supposed to do what i need to do without this check? I tried to use contains but i don't know how to use it with a specific table with a condition

Comment: MySQL <> TSQL. Please specify which RDBMS are you using ?

Comment: SELECT TOP 1 ... ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya syntax is clearly not MySql, and c# and .Net are just irrelevant tags, unless you see code that I don't in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple problems in your code, making it hard to correctly answer your question.
I've copied the code, modified what I could and added comments whenever I've seen a problem (even if I did fix it). Hope it helps.

```
-- I also don't like this condition, it indicates faulty design of the stored procedure
IF @Action = 'UPDATE' BEGIN 
    -- use Exists to solve the "subquery returned more than one result" problem
    IF EXISTS(
        Select 1
        From hDados hd 
        JOIN hRequisicao hr 
            ON hr.IdReq = hd.IdReq 
        WHERE hr.IdColaborador = 3 
        AND IdStatus != 4 
        AND IdStatus != 5
        AND Nome LIKE @Nome
        ) BEGIN
        UPDATE hDados -- use the alias you've used in the from clause
        SET Nome = @Nome, 
            Dados = @Dados, 
            Observacoes = @Observacoes
        -- From clause problem: You are creating a cross join between hRequisicao and hDados tables.
        -- use proper join syntax.
        FROM hRequisicao hr, hDados hd 
        WHERE hr.IdColaborador = @IdColaborador 
        AND Nome LIKE @Nome 
        AND IdStatus != 4 
        AND IdStatus != 5
    END
END ELSE BEGIN    
    -- You can't use a select statement inside the values clause. 
    /*
    INSERT INTO hDados(Nome,Dados,Observacoes,IdReq) 
    VALUES (
        @Nome,
        @Dados,
        @Observacoes,
        (
         Select 
        )
    )
   */
   -- Instead, use insert...select: (Note that this select statement might also return multiple rows!)
    INSERT INTO hDados(Nome,Dados,Observacoes,IdReq) 
    SELECT @Nome, @Dados, @Observacoes, hr.IdReq 
    FROM hRequisicao hr 
    WHERE hr.IdColaborador = @IdColaborador 
    AND IdStatus != 4 
    AND IdStatus != 5

END
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction, for some reason when I tried to use the proper JOIN syntax on update statement it wasn't working so i went with this one and still did the job. Also why should i not use Select statement inside values if i only need it to return 1 value?   And about the Initial condition, I've been doing this to do different commands in each procedure, why is this not alright?

Comment: 1. not really sure why you want a join there in the first place 2. Inside the `values` clause there can only be variables or hard coded values. 3. It's better to have a different procedure for each crud operation - one for insert, one for update, one for delete and one for select.

Comment: I need a join there because I need to know from which Requisition the files in hDados belong to with the condition hr.IdColaborador = @IdColaborador.  I've been just doing a procedure for each table with different commands because this is how they have been doing at where i work